# C# 3.5 Memory problems when reading a big text file, splitted by ; and load the values into a DataTable

Tags: c#

I'm developing in .Net 3.5 and I have a little big issue that if we resolve, we can help other people with same problem.

I'm having issues running out of memory.
I need to read a big text file, around 500mb and 13 millions of lines, each line must be splitted with ; to get the values of the line (around 7 values per line) and load all the values into a DataTable.

I don't know how can I read and load it, without get all the memory of the system.

My PC have 8gb of ram and it gets full.

Thanks

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("Months");
dt.Columns.Add("WHS");
dt.Columns.Add("BRICK");
dt.Columns.Add("DAY");
dt.Columns.Add("SALES TYPE");
dt.Columns.Add("FCC");
dt.Columns.Add("UNITS");

String line;

using (FileStream fs = File.Open("path", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
{
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] parts = line.Split(';');
        dt.Rows.Add(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], parts[3], parts[4], parts[5], parts[6]);
    }
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

**TEMPORAL SOLUTION**

You need to clear de DataTable with a counter (I do all of this in a BackGroundWorker), for example:

```
int counter = 0;
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string[] parts = line.Split(';');
    dt.Rows.Add(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], parts[3], parts[4], parts[5], parts[6]);
    counter++;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

    if(counter >= 500000)
    {
    dt.Clear();
    counter = 0;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Data tables have a LOT of memory overhead ([some tests indicate over 4X overhead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424598)) - you might be better off creating a list of a custom class rather than filling a DataTable.

Comment: try this: `dt.BeginLoadData();
 foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(""))
  dt.Rows.Add(line.Split(new[] {';'}));
 dt.EndLoadData();`

Comment: perhaps adding the machine settings which you are using can also shed some light

Comment: Also a strings will use `20+(n/2)*4 bytes`. At 13 million lines with 7 values per line that could very well lead up to another GByte overhead.

Comment: by the way is there any reason why to read the file using `FileStream` object family instead of simply `File.ReadAllLines()` ? You are treating your content as text anyway. Although this is nearly insignificant, you will spare the creation and management of `FileStream`, `BufferedStream` and `StreamReader` objects.

Comment: From another point of view, isn't there a flaw on the UI? I mean, loading 13 million entries in a data grid. Shouldn't you implement some kind of search functionality to narrow down the result?

Comment: I would suggest to use buffering while reading with a buffer size of around 4K or 8K. 
Next process .

Comment: Well, Ravi just gave one good reason why not to use `File.ReadAllLines` - in case one wants to buffer the reading. `File.ReadAllLines` will read load the whole thing, I guess.

Comment: @PhilDulac has a point. Any dataGirdView that hosts 13 million rows with 7 columns will be horribly slow anyways, even if your RAM can manage it... what exaclty are you trying to achieve with that amount of data in a UI?

Comment: thanks all for the answers, when I try this method, the memory of my pc increase from 2gb to the maximum and crash the PC. I need read the file with the minimum usage of RAM and I don't know how. I need to manage all the data from the file in a DataGridView to compare data. It is my first time with big files and with C#

Comment: If you want load all data at once, I suggest to load all data to an list and set it as DataSource of DataGridView.     `foreach(line...)    myList.Add(new {Months=splittedLine[0], ...});

Comment: I think  the dataGridView can better handle data by using this approach.

Comment: So... you solved the problem by throwing data away. If you're going to throw them away anyway, why load them and keep them in memory in the first place?

Comment: @Luaan true, I will try it. Thanks for all the answers